# xjc handle duplicated elemements

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, xsd, xjc

1. I have three XSD files: a.xsd, b.xsd and c.xsd
2. Each of them contains an xs:element called `MyHeader`
3. I try to use xjc to generate java classes from these three XSD file
4. Error when generating the java file

Here is the common part in all three XSDs:

```xml
<xs:element name="MyHeader">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="Username" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="Password" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The error message is `[xjc] [ERROR] 'MyHeader' is already defined`

Then I try to use external bindings to solve the problem, because I really want `MyHeader` can be ONE java class.

My external binding is like

```xml
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <bindings schemaLocation="./a.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MyHeader']">
            <class name="MyHeader" />
        </bindings>
    </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="./b.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MyHeader']">
            <class name="MyHeader" />
        </bindings>
    </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="./c.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MyHeader']">
            <class name="MyHeader" />
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Then it complains xpath error...

Can someone help me get rid of this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason not to make the complexType part in `MyHeader` a named type, and maybe even move it to a seperate XSD that you import to the other ones?

Comment: a.xsd, b.xsd and c.xsd has the same namespace? can you add more information on plugin of generation?

Answer (score 2):

Your binding file needs the definition of the namespace prefix xs:. After adding this, a rename for MyHeader in one of the three xsd files works.

But you won't be able to rename three clashing element names in three different XML schema files.

One way around this would be to use different namespaces: then the elements wouldn't clash.

Removing the definition of this element from two schema files is another option.

Clearly, the entire schema design is flawed and should be reconsidered using an approach where common types or elements are defined in one file, with other files including this common base file.